# Is there a way to keep observations from a dataset conditional on them being in some list?

Tags: stata

I have one dta file that contains millions of observations, with about 4 variables. I only want to look at a subset of this data, for which the variable `username` is contained in a list of a few hundred usernames. I have two .dta files. One has the full set of data and the other has the "roster" which contains the usernames I want to look specifically at.

Looking through Stata documentation, it seems I want to use `keep if exp` But I do not know what to make the expression. I cannot even load the roster into Stata without clearing out the main dataset from my work space. How do I reference this separate dta document without clearing the main document?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/mt4we1/drop_observations_from_a_dataset_in_stata/  Please tell people in any forum if you are also posting elsewhere. People can feel badly treated if they find the question has already been answered.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is `keep if inlist(username, "user1", "user2", ...)`. The problem is, `inlist()` only allows up to 10 string values to compare. If you have more, you  have to `merge`, or to use regular expressions.

Suppose we have this dataset, saved as all_users.dta:

```
input str6 username
"user_a"
"user_b"
"user_c"
"user_d"
"user_e"
"user_f"
"user_g"
"user_h"
"user_i"
"user_j"
"user_k"
"user_l"
"user_m"
"user_n"
"user_o"
"user_p"
"user_q"
"user_r"
"user_s"
"user_t"
end
```

And we have a second dataset, saved as usernames.dta:

```
input str6 username
"user_a"
"user_b"
"user_c"
"user_d"
"user_e"
"user_f"
"user_g"
"user_h"
"user_i"
"user_j"
"user_k"
"user_l"
"user_m"
"user_n"
"user_o"
end
```

Then these would be two ways to keep only the observations of all_users.dta where username is in usernames.dta:

```
*** MERGE ***
clear
use all_users
merge m:1 username using usernames
keep if _merge == 3

*** REGEX ***
clear
use usernames
levelsof username, local(usernames)
use all_users, clear

// Create regular expression
foreach username of local usernames {
    local regex `regex'|`username'
}
local regex `=substr("`regex'", 2, .)'

keep if regexm(username, "^(`regex')$")
```

Comment: I was writing mine as yours was posted. I think you should be more positive about using `merge`: it is a really good solution!

Comment: I didn't want to sound negative about `merge`! I just wanted to show different ways to do it. But I agree that it's more likely that `merge` is the better option.

Comment: Fine. I certainly recommend that the OP accepts your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The FAQ [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/group-characteristics-for-subsets/) is aimed at precisely this problem. `merge` the datasets and keep the intersection defined by `_merge` being 3.

In principle you could type out one or more commands defining a `keep` condition, but that is a poor solution as

1. It is tedious and error-prone.
2. `inlist()` with string arguments is fiddly in particular if that is part of the solution. (There could be much neater solutions if say what to `keep` can be expressed concisely.)
3. It is a waste of time and effort as you already have the inclusion information to hand.